Warning: Undefined array key 0 releases/80/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/VariationMatrix.php on line 47
A configurable in the Product view opens up with the error message, of which I cannot proceed any further. The children attached can open up without issue. There were not any issues with opening up the any of the items prior.
I updated the Attribute on the children from SIZE to MODEL in Magento as well as in our ERP system.
After the update, I can open up the children without issue after the change, but the Parent opens up with the Error message.
I deleted the Configurable and the Children, and reloaded all, with the correct Attribute in all necessary cells.
All load without issue, but I still cannot open up the Configurable. It gives me the same error message.
I am currently using v2.4.4
